# Subtract a specific string from a variable in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I am making a file converter with batch using FFMPEG.

I have encountered a problem when trying to subtract the name of a file from the complete link to the file to get the directory of the folder it is in so after the file is converted it can be put into that directory.

Can someone advise me on how I could subtract the string from the `filename` variable from the string in the `directory`

My code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set filetype=.flac
for /R %%a in ("*%filetype%*") do (
    set directory=%%a
    set filename=%%~na%filetype%
    set convdir=!directory:%filename%=!
    echo !convdir!
    pause
    ffmpeg -i "%%a" "convdir%%~na.wav"
    echo Converted %%a
)
echo Convertion Done!
pause
```

Comment: read the output of `for /?` regarding for variable modifiers. the approach you are attempting is completely unneccesary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick, untested, example of how I'd suggest your task is performed:

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "TreeRoot=."
Set "FileGlob=*.flac"
Set "ConvExtn=.wav"
For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '"(Set PATHEXT=) & "%__APPDIR__%where.exe" /F /R "%TreeBase%" "%FileGlob%" 2> NUL"'
) Do (
    Echo Converting %%~G to %%~nG%ConvExtn%
    "ffmpeg.exe" -i %%G "%%~dpnG%ConvExtn%"
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 Echo Conversion completed.
)
"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /T 5 1> NUL
```

*Simply adjust the variable values on lines `3` to `5` as necessary. I've used `.` as the tree root as that is the current directory. Please note however, that your code does not define the current directory, so if this is supposed to be rooted at the location of the batch file itself, you should probably change that to `%~dp0.`.*